# Как пишется слова, выражающие звуки типа "м-м-м", а также ""растянутые слова

Tags: тире

1. Через тире или нет пишутся (в художественном тексте) слова, выражающие звуки, например,
   "э-э-э" (или "эээ"), "м-м-м" (или "ммм")?
   Только на одном форуме нашла, что тире ставится, но правило так и не смогла найти.
2. Как правильно проставлять тире в написании слов, которые герой говорит "нараспев", например:
   "Да-а-а, сэ-э-эр" или нужно писать "Д-а-а-а, с-э-э-э-р",
   т.е. первая и последняя буквы растянутого звука обособляются тире от предшествующих и следующих за ними букв?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Через тире или нет...

Через дефис. См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59 :

> **§ 113.** Дефис находит применение также в специальных случаях... в)
> для передачи протяжного звучания
> гласных, раскатистого ***р*** и других
> особенностей произношения, напр.:
> *Антропка! **Антропка-а-а!..** — кричал он с упорным и слезливым
> отчаянием, долго, долго вытягивая
> последний слог (Т.); Ну **о-о-оченъ**
> навязчивая реклама! (из газеты); Это
> было **р-р-р-революционно!**;
> **«П-п-роходите, п-п-пожалуйста»**, — сказал он заикаясь.*